# Is it possible to shorten this code to one line?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to shorten this code to one line?

```
   window.addEventListener('load',function(){
      document.querySelector(".preloader-circle").classList.add('loaded');
      document.querySelector(".preloader").classList.add('loaded');
   });
```

Comment: Any Javascript snippet (or entire script) can be shortened to one line. Whether that's a good idea or not is a different question, though... (and it often isn't)

Comment: yes it is . . .

Comment: @NinaScholz How to do it?

Comment: Remove the line breaks :-)

Comment: Really? Is that just not necessary?

Comment: The only question here is: Why? No, really. Why would you want to have this in "one line"?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: That is not entirely correct. For example single line comments.

Comment: I'm a beginner, and I thought it would be better if it was in one line.

Comment: @JavaScript Can be converted to `/* */` or removed entirely, preserving the logic of the script

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Yes, yet that was not the point.

Comment: As a beginner you really should not think about the _"length"_ of code. There are specialized tools that will do this for you if you really need it short.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("[class^=preloader]").forEach(el => {
    el.classList.add("loaded")
  });
});
```

This will add the `loaded` class to all the elements with selector class with prefix `preloader`

Reference for selector - https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean shorten the code inside the function?

`document.querySelectorAll(".preloader-circle, .preloader").forEach(x=>x.classList.add('loaded'));`

Answer (score -4):

```
function makeAnyCodeAOneLiner(code) {
   console.log(`You're welcome!`);
   return code.split('\n').join('')
}

makeAnyCodeAOneLiner(`window.addEventListener('load',function(){
      document.querySelector(".preloader-circle").classList.add('loaded');
      document.querySelector(".preloader").classList.add('loaded');
   });`)
```

Comment: Hey, it shortens the code to one line. Plus, it's reusable! :-P

Comment: Seriously though, Raj's answer.